# Pandas multi indexing not working

Tags: pandas

I have below code,

```
purchase_1 = pd.Series({'Name': 'Chris', 'Item Purchased': 'Dog Food',                
'Cost': 22.50})
purchase_2 = pd.Series({'Name': 'Kevyn', 'Item Purchased': 'Kitty Litter',
                    'Cost': 2.50})
purchase_3 = pd.Series({'Name': 'Vinod', 'Item Purchased': 'Bird Seed',
                    'Cost': 5.00})

df = pd.DataFrame([purchase_1, purchase_2, purchase_3], 
index=['Store 1', 'Store 1', 'Store 2'])
```

I added below code to change the indexes - But, when append the new row, it is giving weird results. Please help me:

```
df['location'] = df.index
df.set_index(['location', 'Name'])
df = df.append(pd.Series(data={'Cost': 3.00, 'Item Purchased': 'Kitty 
Food'}, name=('Store 2', 'Kevyn')))
print (df)
```

Comment: What are the weird results you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You forget assign `df`:

```
df['location'] = df.index
#assign back to df
df = df.set_index(['location', 'Name'])
df = df.append(pd.Series(data={'Cost': 3.00, 'Item Purchased': 'Kitty Food'},
                         name=('Store 2', 'Kevyn')))
print (df)
                Cost Item Purchased
location Name                      
Store 1  Chris  22.5       Dog Food
         Kevyn   2.5   Kitty Litter
Store 2  Vinod   5.0      Bird Seed
         Kevyn   3.0     Kitty Food
```

Simplier solution is [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with parameter `append=True`, if want new index names use [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = df.set_index('Name', append=True).rename_axis(['location','Name'])
df = df.append(pd.Series(data={'Cost': 3.00, 'Item Purchased': 'Kitty Food'}, 
                         name=('Store 2', 'Kevyn')))
print (df)
                Cost Item Purchased
location Name                      
Store 1  Chris  22.5       Dog Food
         Kevyn   2.5   Kitty Litter
Store 2  Vinod   5.0      Bird Seed
         Kevyn   3.0     Kitty Food
```

And if not necessary name of first level of `MultiIndex`:

```
df = df.set_index('Name', append=True)
df = df.append(pd.Series(data={'Cost': 3.00, 'Item Purchased': 'Kitty Food'}, 
                         name=('Store 2', 'Kevyn')))
print (df)
               Cost Item Purchased
        Name                      
Store 1 Chris  22.5       Dog Food
        Kevyn   2.5   Kitty Litter
Store 2 Vinod   5.0      Bird Seed
        Kevyn   3.0     Kitty Food
```